# make fetch direct the user to the POST page as a regular form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use fetch to make post request, The problem is that the user has not been direct to the Post page (as regular form direct the user to post page)
I want in the server side at `app.post('/userProfile')` Navigate the user to a certain place according to information

```
  fetch('/userProfile', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: json
  })
```

I did not find an answer in Google or anywhere unfortunately

Comment: From server side return json where you can specify if you want to redirect, if yes what url, then receive the response on client side and redirect like `document.location.href = 'new url'` if you are working on some framework like React then you can use framework's Route api

Comment: What is your backend made of?

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of using Ajax (via `fetch` or any other API) is that the response is returned to your JavaScript instead of being handled by the browser's default handling of a link or form submission.

While the response to an Ajax request can be a `302` or `301` response with a `Location` header, that tells the browser that "What you asked for can be found over here". It *doesn't* tell the browser "Load this URL in the main viewport". The redirect is followed and the result is returned to the Ajax.

---

If you want the browser to navigate to the new URL: Use a regular form submission or link. Don't use Ajax.

Comment: I would really like to do this, the problem is that I use a rich text editor, quill, and the text it produces is not sent like a standard form

Comment: Then write JS to insert it into a standard form and submit that.

Comment: The solution I was thinking of is to create a new element to hide it from the page and inject the text into it, but isn't that a bit problematic? There must be a more direct way to do this